# How to access an image stored on the server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, file-upload, glassfish-3

I have a web application that is hosted on jelastic.com. I uploaded an image into the home directory of the server by using the path `/opt/glassfish3/temp`. The code is as follows:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/opt/glassfish3/temp/" + fileName);
            fos.write(uploadedFile.getContents());
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
```

I am using an image tag to show the image file but its giving me a broken image. The html code is as follows:

```
<img src="/opt/glassfish3/temp/${sessionScope['userdet']['image']}" width="200px" ></img>
```

Comment: you could resolve this? i had the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Home folder in Jelastic is used mainly for storage purposes. You had better save your files in the folders of your web server.
Therefore try to substitute the code you use:

`FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/opt/glassfish3/temp/" + fileName)`

with this one:

`FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/
domain1/applications/{PUT_HERE_CONTEXT_NAME}/" + fileName);`

Then modify html code:

`<img src="/opt/glassfish3/temp/${sessionScope['userdet']['image']}" width="200px" ></img>
->
<img src="${sessionScope['userdet']['image']}" width="200px" ></img>`

Comment: I think the file is getting saved on the web server by using the `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/ domain1/applications/{PUT_HERE_CONTEXT_NAME}/" + fileName);`
but image is not displayed, its is giving me a broken image, is there something more that I need to add to the src.